# Two folders with weird names with huge size. What are those? What should I do with them?

Tags: windows-7

I have two folders in my WinDrive (i.e. the C drive. There details are:

Name of Folder1 - 7bf7d36518538dd519e14b5f
  3.85 GB (4,14,42,50,880 bytes) :: 50,287 Files, 6,782 Folders

Name of Folder2 - c077d2de493f37d8df
4.62 GB (4,97,01,76,512 bytes) :: 31,856 Files, 15,990 Folders

I don't know what to do with them. Is this encryption? If yes, then how can I know their real names? Can I delete them? What are they here for?

On Google search, I found that these may contain some Windows7-SP1 files.

I tried renaming/removing those, showed that the process was in use. Tried all the hashes to decode the string, google searched with names of all the major subfolders/files inside the folders.

Also tried uploading few files and applications to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com) Nothing popped up.. I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium

Comment: Those are not encrypted names just random names there is a huge difference.

Comment: Ok, but what to do with these?

Comment: What could be possibly the reason of a downvote on this?

Comment: One possible reason is that its not a well researched question.  The folders are clearly the result of Windows default behavior of looking for the hdd with the largest amount of free space as a temp directory for updates that are released.

Comment: I did a hell lot of research and finally arrived on this by stackoverflow. I really do not understand why it is necessary that you need to have this much amount of knowledge to ask a question.

Now about the folders, it is not that clear that these are the results of windows default behavior. Next, I cannot rename them, so that means someone's using any process. Adding to that, I was having some Malware Problems with the system and this was looking like a suspect to me.

Comment: @explorer if you've done your research, mention it in the question, saves all of us time in mentioning have you done xyz when you already have.

Comment: @Sathya Thanks for telling. I have added those things. Will take care of this thing in future.

Comment: Are there in your Windows directory or in the root of disk? That makes a huge difference.

Comment: The location is: `C:/Folder1` and `C:/Folder2`

Comment: @explorer - I still believe them to be directories created by Windows to install applications per the default behavior of Windows going out to the largest drive to do so.  The fact they contain Windows file more or less confirms this.  They exist so you can uninstall the updates in question.  If you don't care to do that then delete the folders.

Comment: @Ramhound one thing more I would like to know is, what are these names? Is there any specific pattern or algo behind them? Finally, I will be deleting them now!

Comment: @explorer - They are unique id's I am sure there is some logic.  these directories are normally located in a folder invisible to the user by default for a reason.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the info! I will try to find out about their nomenclature! Deleted! Peace!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to download an antivirus-antimalware. Folders with long random file names are temp folders made by installers. You can delete them anytime.

Comment: Why did they not get deleted automatically?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe at Microsoft (the main suspect for these folders) they're too bored to make a script that deletes them.

Comment: @explorer - Actually its not.  The folders were created to install an Windows update more then likely.  They are not deleted because without the folders you wouldn't be able to uninstall the update.

Comment: @Ramhound - Didn't know that...

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge. But it had been a lot of time since I installed those updates. Generally, are they needed now? Can I delete them?

Comment: @explorer Most certainly, *yes*.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest you run an antivirus and/or an anti-malware check on your computer first. I haven't had stumbled upon something like that and chances are that they're some kind of the result of the presence of malware. Here are some useful resources:

Anti-malware:

- [Adwcleaner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers)
- [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)

If they don't trow any alerts on those directories or the files within them, they're probably some files some application you have installed generated. Here are some steps to know whether they're harmful or necessary:

- Change their names or locations, adding a `.bak` at the end of the filename usually works. Try to do this from secure mode if they're blocked or in use.
- Check if your applications still work fine without them. If you notice an important or a trusted application broke, just rename them to their original names and leave them there. They're *necessary*.

If everything works fine but they can't be deleted or regenerated, it may be some malware that slipped through your previous tests. In that case:

- Look for suspicious processes and startup applications and services on your machine. Disable or uninstall them. If that doesn't work, find the executables involved and delete them from another machine or even from a Linux Live Distro (to avoid access or permissions issues).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try the above solution. However, I already tried a full scan with MSE and nothing popped out.

Comment: As far as I know, and by experience, MSE is not one of the best software out there for this task. Much malware slips through it actually, and note that malware =/= virus. Your antivirus may be letting some malware pass their scans too.

Comment: Okay I agree, but if I am not wrong, MSE in Windows 7  disables Windows Defender because it has inbuilt Malware protection.
Although, Malwarebytes is scanning my system now.

Comment: It depends on the definitions your software relies on. If some treat hasn't been recognized yet, your antivirus/anti-malware software won't recognize it at all (unless it uses some heuristics). That's why you should scan with different apps, but this doesn't mean you ought to have two av's running at the same time, they'll most likely interfere with each other. Gee, that's why I love my Linux box, hehe.

Comment: I also tried uploading few files on [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com). Nothing popped out. Scanned it with MalwareBytes, MSE, Avast. (All updated)

Comment: @explorer - Windows Defender is not disable if MSE is installed.  Windows Defender is malware and MSE is anti-virus.  This statement only applies to Windows 7.  MSE is fine for 99% of the people it has failed me less times then products I have paid upwards of $60 every year for.

Comment: @Ramhound Finally, someone answered my queries. However, I would like to share [a link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/mse-protect_start/windows-defender-and-microsoft-security-essentials/5309cb8d-02e1-40e8-974f-0dcedb9ab9fd) with you. Please visit this and give a look at the third question. MSE works for me too always. Not that I paid for any other software, but I tried all the freewares and was stick to MSE for 3 years until that Ads by OfferWizard and ProcessUsage.exe virus made my life hell.

Comment: @explorer - What you describe isn't a virus, its adware, ALL anti-virus security software is horrible at adware. There are better solutions to remove infections that fall into the description that is adware.  I stand by MSE/Windows Defender(Win8+) for the simple fact I use other security software to simply block malicious content in the first place.

Comment: @explorer did you try adwcleaner too? It has other malware definitions.

Comment: @Ramhound What you use to block malicious content at the first place? Other tools take a lot of memory, unlike MSE.

Comment: @arielnmz Yes! That too. Though I have found the bug and removed it manually.

Comment: @arielnmz - Malwarebytes Pro it blocks known ip addresses which in the past have been used to serve malicious files.

Comment: @explorer what was the bug in question?